# Merge sort - sorting only 2^n number of elements

Tags: c++, sorting, mergesort

I have problem with my program. My algorithm don't want to merge if number of element is different then 2^n. It perform operations before merging.For instance for input `13 5 10 8 6 22 11 3 12 20 7 9 14 17 19 1 2 18` it returns `1,3,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,17,19,20,22,2,18,`, it works for pos from 1 to 16 then from 17 to 18

***Functions***

```
void mergeSort(int arr[], int arrSort[], int first, int mid, int last) {
    int from = first;
    int to = mid;
    for (int i = first; i<last; i++) {
        if ((arr[from] <= arr[to] && from<mid) || to >= last) {
            arrSort[i] = arr[from];
            from++;
        } else if ((arr[to]<arr[from] && to<last) || from >= mid) {
            arrSort[i] = arr[to];
            to++;
        }
    }
    for (int i = first; i<last; i++)
        arr[i] = arrSort[i];
}

void mergeSortIter(int array[], int size) {
    int *a = new int[size];
    for (int i = 1; i <= size; i *= 2) {
        showArray(array, size);
        for (int j = i; j <= size; j += (2 * i))
            mergeSort(array, a, j - i, j, min((j + i), size));
    }
}
```

***Rest of the code***

https://pastebin.com/2ugS5ZpZ

To test it you need to write `mi 6` [enter] (6 is number of elements) then elements with space for example `5 6 8 2 1 3` [enter]

Comment: One part of the problem is your final for loop, where the index only goes through powers of two. There might be a deeper design problem as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was very trivial. I wasn't printing final array...